# Properly feed paths to executables in bash script

Tags: bash, awk, path, for

Hello all I have a text file (1.txt) that contains full paths to binaries which I need to execute a command (val_bin) for each path in the file.

1.txt Example:

```
/source/ed/dev/ed/ab/ed_len/comercial/bin/APP1.bin 
/source/ed/dev/ed/ab/ed_lap/comercial/bin/APP2.bin 
/source/ed/dev/ed/ab/ky_len/Industrial/bin/APP3.bin
...
```

Command Example:  val_bin-  Creates an html file for every record in 1.txt
e.g.

```
val_bin -output <DESTINATION.html> -path </source/ed/dev/ed/ab/ed_len/comercial/bin/APP1.bin>
```

where -output should have the path where the html files will be created after each time the command ends ("DESTINATION"). 
where -output should specify name.bin.html (e.g. App1.bin.html)

where -path needs to be the entire path fed into the command

example output: (where /tmp is the destination of the html files)

```
> ll /tmp
/tmp/APP1.bin.html
/tmp/APP2.bin.html
/tmp/APP3.bin.html
...
```

Ive tried several different loop options but now am investigating pure awk.

Answer (score 2):

No scripting required.

```
xargs -I NAME val_bin -output /tmp/$(basename NAME).html -path NAME < 1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want this:

```
dest_dir=/tmp
while IFS= read -r bin; do
    if [[ ! -f "$bin" ]]; then
        printf "No such file: %s\n" "$bin"
    else
        output="$dest_dir/$(basename "$bin").html"
        val_bin -output "$output" -path "$bin"
    fi
done < 1.txt
```